# Quick Edit setup and usage

Tags: 7, nodes

[image: Quick Edit Screen Shot]

I added quick edit to my site. Made sure all the correct libraries are in place and see the **quick edit** button in the gear next to the content, but am not getting any way to save the changes.

The screenshot shows what I see when I click in the content area.

I have CKEditor in place. Have tried CDN and Libraries version without success.

Is there a certain type of field or class I need to add to fields?

Comment: Have you made a change to the text? Any errors on admin/reports/status? Any js errors on the page?

Comment: @nmillin There are 2 errors - Page Not Found:  sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/enhanced_image/plugin.js and sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/drupal_path/plugin.js The text changes happen on screen, but don't save.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors you are reporting, it seems that you haven't downloaded the actual javascript ckeditor library.

You can do it manually, as described in http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7/Installation.

or you can script it (update the version if needed):

```
wget http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor/CKEditor%204.5.4/ckeditor_4.5.4_standard.zip
unzip ckeditor_4.5.4_standard.zip
mv ckeditor $SITENAME/sites/all/libraries
rm ckeditor_4.5.4_standard.zip
```